# XSD custom namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I am starting to play with XML and XSD; I have the simple **xsd** file called *narrative.xsd* and another one called *goal.xsd* which includes the narrative.

The problem is that in *goal.xsd* for the `Timescale` type I get this error:

```
the http://mdmw.co.uk:Timescale is not declared.
```

If I omit the namespace then it is working.

How can I get it to work with namespaces?

Thanks in advance.

This is *narrative.xsd*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="narrative"
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      targetNamespace="http://mdmw.co.uk"
      xmlns="http://mdmw.co.uk"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  >
    <xs:element name="Timescale">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="1 Month" />
                <xs:enumeration value="2 Months" />
                <xs:enumeration value="3 Months" />
                <xs:enumeration value="6 Months" />
                <xs:enumeration value="9 Months" />
                <xs:enumeration value="1 Year" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is *goal.xsd*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="goal"
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      targetNamespace="http://mdmw.co.uk"
      xmlns="http://mdmw.co.uk"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  >    
    <xs:include schemaLocation="narrative.xsd"/>      
    <xs:element name="goals">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="goalType" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="timeScale" type="Timescale" />
                    <xs:element name="currentResult" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element name="currentResultDate" type="xs:date"/>
                    <xs:element name="comments" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>   
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: XML looks good.  I verified in VS from following menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml into view.  Errors will show up in Error List just like any other compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeScale` element declaration refers to the type `Timescale`, but `Timescale` is an element, not a type.

The error should disappear if the anonymous simple type inside the `Timescale` element is turned into a top-level simple type with this name in *narrative.xsd*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="narrative"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://mdmw.co.uk"
    xmlns="http://mdmw.co.uk"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  >
    <xs:simpleType name="Timescale">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="1 Month" />
            <xs:enumeration value="2 Months" />
            <xs:enumeration value="3 Months" />
            <xs:enumeration value="6 Months" />
            <xs:enumeration value="9 Months" />
            <xs:enumeration value="1 Year" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Ghislain, I will try it tomorrow morning; as for the namespaces are they OK ? I need to find some clear documentation about xmlns, elementFormDefault etc... Google will be my best friennd I guess

Comment: My pleasure to help, brillox. Yes, the namespaces look great, even though it is more common, to improve schema readability, to bind the target namespace to a prefix rather than making it default. Also, you might find the brand new stackoverflow documentation feature of help as a starting point (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xml/topics). XML Schema will probably follow later as the community contributes.

Comment: wow.. stackoverflow is a myth... now with the documentation project is even better!!!